# Accessing web config value from asp:ListItem

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to print the value I have stored in the web config as text for a list item.

```
            <asp:ListItem  Enabled="true" Selected="true" Text="Web Only - <%$ AppSettings:SubscriptionPrice %>"
                Value="web" />
```

will give me: Web Only - <%$ AppSettings:SubscriptionPrice %>

However, if I remove the Web Only text and do this:

```
            <asp:ListItem  Enabled="true" Selected="true" Text="<%$ AppSettings:SubscriptionPrice %>"
                Value="web" />
```

I'll get the variable desired. Is there a way to have the text and the value from my appsettings?

Comment: I think it will also work to use single quotes for the text value.  I don't have time to verify it though.  In paperwork hades...  <asp:ListItem  Enabled="true" Selected="true" Text='Web Only - <%$ AppSettings:SubscriptionPrice %>' Value="web" />

Comment: @CMKanode That didn't work. It gives me the same text as the first way I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it inline that easily. Your options are:

1. Set the complete value in your AppSettings. (easy)
2. Set the value from code behind. (easy)
3. Lastly, if you want to be in ASPX and nothing else is acceptable, you need to write a  CodeExpressionBuilder so that you can provide custom code, as follows: (may be an overkill)

here is the code expression builder

```
namespace Funky
{
    [System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionPrefix("Code")]
    public class CodeExpressionBuilder : System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilder
    {
        public override System.CodeDom.CodeExpression GetCodeExpression(BoundPropertyEntry entry,
           object parsedData, System.Web.Compilation.ExpressionBuilderContext context)
        {
            return new System.CodeDom.CodeSnippetExpression(entry.Expression);
        }
    }
}
```

add this web.config entry

```
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <expressionBuilders>
      <add expressionPrefix="MyCode" type="Funky.CodeExpressionBuilder"/>
    </expressionBuilders>
  </compilation>
```

finally use the code expression as follows:

```
<asp:ListItem  Enabled="true" Selected="true" Text='<%$ MyCode: "Web Only - " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionPrice"]  %>' Value="web" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do this on page, but you can do this in your code file:

```
ListItem item = new ListItem();
item.Text = "Web Only - " +  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SubscriptionPrice"];
item.Value = "web";
item.Selected = true;
ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the earlier post.

I think you are going to have to bind the value is code.

```
ddl.Items.Clear()
ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem("Web Only -" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SubscriptionPrice"), "Web"))
```